# Running computation in Spark in a single node

Tags: java, key, apache-spark, key-value

I have an RDD like so:

`JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point> keyValuePair = ...`

I want to output an RDD like so:

`JavaRDD<Point> valuesRemainingAfterProcessing = processAndOutputSkylinePoints(keyValuePair)`

The processing will take place in a single node because all the values are needed for the processing to occur. (doing comparisons between them and their flags)

What I thought of doing is:

1. Map everything to a single ID: `JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<PointFlag, Point>> singleIdRDD = keyValuePair.mapToPair(fp -> new Tuple2(0, fp));`
2. Do the processing: `JavaRDD<Iterable<Point>> iterableGlobalSkylines = singleIdRDD.map(ifp -> calculateGlobalSkyline(ifp));` (calculateGlobalSkyline() returns a `List<Point>`)
3. Convert to `JavaRDD<Point>`: `JavaRDD<Point> globalSkylines = iterableGlobalSkylines.flatMap(p -> p);`

This all though looks like a dirty hack to me and I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: If all data fits on a single node, on a single key, you need to ask yourself the question of whether you need to use Spark. To me, it looks like than using 'traditional' programming techniques will get you the desired result.

Comment: @maasg Computations before this one are proper Spark parallel computations. The problem is that I need to benchmark the different Skyline algorithms and one of them (BNL) has a step where it uses a single node to do the final computation therefore I need the whole computation to run on a cluster in order to benchmark it accurately even if that means I run it on a single node for a specific step. Any other way I believe it will run on the driver side. In the end I found the solution which I posted as a candidate answer.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution I found (definitely way less verbose) is to use the `glom()` function from the Spark API. This function returns a single `List` of all the elements of the previous RDD or in official terms:

`Return an RDD created by coalescing all elements within each partition into a list.`

First though you have to reduce the RDD to a single partition. Here is the solution:

```
JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point> keyValuePair = ...;
JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point> singlePartition = keyValuePair.coalesce(1);
JavaRDD<List<Tuple2<PointFlag, Point>>> groupedOnASingleList = keyValuePair.glom();
JavaRDD<Point> globalSkylinePoints = groupedOnASingleList.flatMap(singleList -> getGlobalSkylines(singleList));
```

If anyone has a better answer feel free to post it.